# "Failed to load PDF document"

Tags: php, pdf

I want to open the pdf file on my browser, but the file won't open. Chrome said "Failed to load PDF document". Please help.

Here's my code:

```
<?
include 'connection.php';
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book");
$p=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$ebook=$p['ebook'];
$title=$p['title'];
$file = "admin/upload/$ebook";
$filename = "$title";
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about debugging? Remove your header() calls and debug your variables by simple var_dump() calls. Also use file_exists() to check if the file exists and is readable. Also I'm wondering why you send `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');` while there's no logic which would allow byte request responses?

Comment: Whats the outcome of `$file`? And where did you define `$title`?

Comment: well, first things first, I'm not really familiar with PHP. I got this code from this site. The said it worked. the $file is supposed to link to my pdf file in that directory

Comment: What is the outcome of `$file`? It is likely the file doesn't exist.

Comment: admin/upload is where i put my pdf files. which I'm trying to show/read on my browser. and $file is supposed to call to my pdf file in that directory, with a name that is saved in my database, field ebook. I checked, and the file is there.

Comment: I think the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` header is confusing the Chrome PDF renderer. Try removing some of those extra headers until it at least opens the PDF properly.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure if this approach is applicable to your situation, if you are running jQuery this will accomplish what you are trying to do according to your question:

No db query is required... you can use `glob('admin/upload/*')`

PHP code:

```
echo '<select id="getPDF" name="getPDF">';
        echo '<label>Select PDF</label>';
        echo '<option value=""> Select PDF</option>';
            foreach(glob('admin/upload/*') as $specific_pdf) {
            $this_pdf = str_replace('.pdf','',basename($specific_pdf)); 
            $this_pdf = ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',$this_content));
            $this_pdf_url = $specific_pdf; # ADJUST THIS TO FULL URL TO PDF
            echo '<option value="'.$this_pdf_url.'">'.$this_pdf.'</option>';                            
            }   
    echo '</select>';
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#getPDF" ).change(function(){       
        var pdf_url = $(this).val();                            
        window.open(pdf_url);
    });

});
```

This will open the pdf in a new window/tab.